# create unique IDs for DynamoDB items

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have question about **DynamoDB**, or rather how to model a table.

### Problem description:

**Goal**: Users can save price alerts for products.

**For example**: A user wants to save an alert for when the price for product x is less than a target price.

What I want to persist specifically are: *product, userId, targetPrice, operator*.

operator could be equal, less or greater (I would do the validation of these values in a step before persisting).

A user can add multiple alerts for the same product where the targetPrice and/or the operator would differ. If all of those attributes are the same then it should not create a duplicate item in the db.

And the alerts should be completely separated for each user of course.

My main "**read**" case is to get all the alerts for a product.

My current solution is to have product as the primary key (whenever I mention product than I am talking about a unique identifier for a product) and an alertId as sort key.

The alertId is a composite key of all the attributes: `product:userId:targetPrice:operator`.

So for example: `greatBook12:1234:34:lesser`.

here is some example code in node for persisting the alert:

```
const params = {
  TableName: TABLE_NAME,
  Item: {
    userId,
    alertId: `${product}:${userId}:${targetPrice}:${operator}`,
    product,
    targetPrice,
    operator
  },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_OLD'
};
docClient.put(params) // ...
```

### My Question:

It feels kinda wrong to misuse the sort key like that. While it does cover all my requirements (no duplicates, read is easy and should be relatively fast) I was wondering if there isn't a better way of doing this. Maybe with indices or the like?

I kinda like the flat data structure (just items in a table) but maybe there is another way of creating unique alerts for different targetPrices/operators/products/users without creating duplicates?

So I guess my question is: Is there a better way of doing this while fulfilling the requirements I am working with?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question. From one side with `product` partition key you've querying simplicity but you also distribute your data unevenly. What if one product will have a big success and take 50% of all load ("hot partitions" problem detailed here https://cloudonaut.io/dynamodb-pitfall-limited-throughput-due-to-hot-partitions/) ? In such case you'll probably encounter reading or writing throtlling. DynamoDB advises to use some randomness (e.g. random values (1, 1000)) to avoid such uneven distribution. You can learn more about these strategies here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html#bp-partition-key-sharding-random

But it depends on how you're certain about hot partitions risk. If you're sure to not have them (products with much more alerts than others), maybe it's better to keep the schema simple for now ?